# Show that the following set is not algebraic.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

How can I prove that the set $\{(z, w) \in \mathbb{C}^2; |z|+|w| = 1 \}$ is not algebraic? I just need a hint. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: complex algebraic sets have even topological dimension. The set provided 
Has odd dimension since it is codimension $1$ in a $4$ dimensional space.

In fact it's not even real algebraic.